# how to retrieve variable arguments in lua 5.2

Tags: lua

The reference pages all say things like

```
function this(...)
end
```

However when I try to apply the supposed `arg` variable all I get is a nil reference. Any attempt I've made to capture the arguments results in a nil table. I've tried forcing a `local tab = {...}` and still get the nil reference. The closest I've managed to get to capturing the arguments is a `select("#",...)` which only returns the number of arguments. Whenever I try to capture this outside parameter declaration I get nothing but another error...

I've been thoroughly looking into this with no avail... any way I can accomplish this without forcibly passing a table?

Answer (score 4):

The `arg` argument is for Lua 5.0 only. Since Lua 5.1, the vararg expression `...` is used instead.

Try this:

```
function foo(...)
    for k, v in ipairs{...} do
        print(k, v)
    end
end

foo('hello', 'world')
```

Comment: strange...it wasn't working in the slightest last night but now it's working just fine...